# GNOME Software shows less programs than Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 16.04, gnome-software

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 to 16.04 and got the GNOME Software which will be replacing Ubuntu Software Center.

However, most applications that would show up in the searches I did in USC wouldn't show up in GNOME Software.

In this

[image: screenshot]

I search the word "steam" in both of them and you can see how most results don't show up in GNOME Software.

As I have upgraded my system, I have both software centers and I can gladly use USC, but if I do a clean install of 16.04 I shouldn't get USC anymore, so why GNOME Software doesn't show that programs and how can I make them show?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can still install USC (package `software-center`) after a new install if you want.  I'm not sure if the selection in Ubuntu/Gnome Software will improve in the future and/or if you can make it show more applications.

Comment: You're not alone, it is broken. It does not index all apps in repos, I think it is a known issue and will probably be fixed in the future. For now I would recommend synaptic or muon software center ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2Akih2pjLc

Comment: @pst007x is correct. I have happily ignored USC and the Gnome thing for years. synaptic runs fine. It is dependable clear, and benefits from a decade of experience. I don't see an app called "steam". If that's necessary, you are probably pulling packages from a repository I don't know of...

Comment: If anyone is interested - there is a [discussion of community.ubuntu.com about software installation of the modern Ubuntu](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/software-installation-on-modern-ubuntu/2555). Muon may be good alternative for Synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why gnome software does not show as many software however I do know that there is definitely no way to change the software it shows using the GUI if it can be done using the command line then I do not know how to do it