# Why doesn't gnome-software show available software?

Tags: canonical, gnome-software

Why doesn't gnome-software show all available software from my repositories?

In other words, is gnome-software restricted in some way by Canonical from listing all available software packages? If so, which software is restricted and which software is allowed? Also, when was this change made and why was this change made?

(Note, I'm not looking for a technical solution).

I've looked at similar questions, but I don't see a clear answer to my question.

[GNOME Software shows less programs than Ubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761269/gnome-software-shows-less-programs-than-ubuntu-software-center)

[Ubuntu 16.04 software center doesn't have many apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761126/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-doesnt-have-many-apps)

[The GNOME Software center shows few apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050694/the-gnome-software-center-shows-few-apps)

Here are a couple of example applications that are not available in gnome-software:

- *torcs*
- *trigger-rally*

But a command-line search with apt shows these applications are actually available to install:

```
apt search ^torcs$
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
torcs/disco 1.3.7+dfsg-4 amd64
  3D racing cars simulator game using OpenGL

apt search ^trigger-rally$
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
trigger-rally/disco 0.6.6+dfsg-2 amd64
  free 3D rally racing car game
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/773640/why-does-ubuntu-software-center-not-show-every-package-available

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1175586/edit) the question to offer an example that we can reproduce?